# Get stacktrace of called function variables

Tags: typescript

I have a parent class

```
class Parent {
    protected functionItems = []

    public doit() {
       this.functionItems.forEach(f => f())
    }
}
```

which calls every function of a member array.

The children of this class merely populate the function array

```
class Child extends Parent {
   protected functionItems = [
     () => { console.log('Hello') },
     () => { throw new Error('here') }
    ]
}
```

Now this example shows my problem: The second function will throw, but the stacktrace only hints to `Parent.doit`. I can hardly find the true origin of the exception.

The output here is `Child.<anonymous> (src/Parent.js:5)`, I would be happy if could just identify which function it was or better which function and line no inside.

Perhaps it is possible to mark the function somehow? I cannot switch to named members since the array is important to be able to generically loop over the items.

Comment: You should create named functions instead of creating anonymous functions. If you use anonymous functions, in the stacktrace, you will see the function named as `<anonymous>` but in case of named functions, you will see the actual name.

Comment: That's correct, I see a line like `Child.<anonymous> (src/Parent.js:5)` I would be happy if could just identify which function it was or better which function and line no inside.

Comment: "I cannot switch to named members since the array is important to be able to generically loop over the items." — You're wrong. ```functionItems = [
  function x() { console.log('Hello') },
  function y() { throw new Error('here') }
 ]```

Comment: That sounds great but does not work, see https://jsfiddle.net/swfv7h1m/, the chosen name is not shown

Comment: @olidem Your jsfiddle includes anonymous functions...

Comment: @pink Ah great, I changed it, this works. https://jsfiddle.net/nd7oytam/

Comment: @quentin I'd accept your answer if you supplied one.